# An equality between right ideals and Jacobson radical

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, noncommutative-algebra

Let $R$ be a unital ring with Jacobson radical $J(R)$. If for any right ideal $I$ of $R$ we have $I+J(R)=I^2+J(R)$ could we deduce that $I$ is the sum of an idempotent right ideal and a nil right ideal? (By the hypothesis, of course $I\subseteq I^2+J(R)$.)

Comment: This is not clear. Are you assuming that for all right ideals $I$ we have $I+J(R)=I^2+J(R)$, or are you assuming that this holds for some special ideal $I$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is no, a counterexample follows.

Let $R$ be any DVR with unique maximal ideal $J$ (which is also the Jacobson radical of $R$). In particular the equality $$I+J=J=I^2+J$$ is trivially satisfied for all ideals $I$. Moreover, recall that all ideals have the form $J^n$ for some $n \ge 0$. The unque idempotent ideal is thus $J^0=R$, and the unique nil ideal is $0$ (there are no nonzero nilpotent elements). Hence the sum of an idempotent ideal and a nil ideal is necessarily $R$, which turns out to be distinct from $I$ in general.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! If we add the condition that $J(R)$ is nil, is the answer to my question "yes"?

Comment: Well, $\{0\}$ is an idempotent ideal too, so I wouldn't say $R$ is the unique idempotent ideal... but the same conclusion follows!